# Computing Probability of default using below mentioned data

Tags: credit-risk, statistical-finance, default-probability, merton-model, black-scholes-merton

So, I am trying to create a  model using the data such as Credit defaults swap of some companies, their historical stock market price, government bond yield.
I am trying to create a Black Scholes Merton model like?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: You can get risk-neutral probabilities of default from credit default swap quotes combined with LGD assumptions.  For physical PD, you may want to look into Kealhofer, Merton, Vasicek (KMV) -like models https://w4.stern.nyu.edu/finance/docs/pdfs/Seminars/123w-vasicek.pdf

Comment: What;s risk-neutral PD? I am trying to calculate 1 year PD and Life time PD. I understand Merton only considers PD at the time of maturity. So, I am open to something that gives PD before maturity as well.

Comment: Risk-neutral probabilities are used to price financial instruments under no-arbitrage condition.  They're not the same as actual probabilities.  One discussion of the difference: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.iimb.2011.06.005